# Preforming an Administrative task, with a service account, via batch

Tags: permissions, batch

Trying to install a piece of software from a network location, and everything works great except the software requires admin rights to install.

Is there a way I can pre enter an admin service account that will allow this to install? Without the user needing to provide the details?

Alternately, is there a way I can give the batch file Admin rights thus passing them off to the Installer file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way I have found to do this is to create a small AutoIT executable that does a run as, eg:

```
$User="User"
$Pass="Pass"
$Domain="Domain"
$Executable="\\your\path\here.exe"
RunAs($User,$Domain,$Pass, 1, $Executable, @SystemDir )
```

You will want to use a temporary account for this purpose as it is theoretically possible to reverse engineer out the ID and password encoded in the EXE file.

EDIT - the $Executable path listed above should be the path to your batch file.

Comment: Do both batch files need to be converted to EXE? the Run as and the actual script? When I try running the code you provided, it simply scrolls through the output line over and over indefinitely.

Comment: \\dcifs04\gpofiles>$User="user"
'$User' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.